# Long occluding geometries in Resonance Audio for Unity

Tags: unity, audio, sound

I'm currently looking into using resonance audio (https://resonance-audio.github.io/resonance-audio/) for accurately modelling the audio for an environment that approximates to a long corridor with a series of bends. I want to have a sound at the end of this corridor that the user can hear at any point in the corridor based on the sound reflections along the corridor.

I have tried a few of the options presented by Resonance Audio:

- Placing reverb probes along the corridor. This seems like the ideal option, however a reverb probe will only apply its baked in reverb profile to sound sources inside the probe. If I try to make the probes larger then they seem to take into account all of the geometry of the corridor at once and things get exceedingly echo-ey and consistent regardless of where I am in the corridor.
- Turning the corridor model into an audio room. This isn't apropriate as it has many of the same issues as a large reverb probe, and also doesn't actually model the space itself.

Has anyone had any experience with hearing distant sounds in Resonance Audio environments like this? At this point I have a feeling that Resonance Audio is just not built for this particular situation.

Comment: Have you considered recording a few versions of your sound, say playing the original sound and recording what it sounds like at the first bend, then playing that recording at the first bend and recording what it sounds like at the second, etc... then cross-fading the sounds and sources as the player progresses down the corridor? Effectively you're "baking in" the reverb from parts of the corridor too distant to be captured by the nearest probe.